# Run-time error ‘713’: Class not registered looking for object with clsid : {59245250-7A2F-11D0-9482-00A0C9111OED}

Tags: windows, vb.net, ms-access

I´ve got an old programm, which is using access as DB. So far I could install it but on start I get the following error:

```
Run-time error ‘713’: Class not registered looking for object with clsid : {59245250-7A2F-11D0-9482-00A0C9111OED}
```

The programm was written in VB but I´ve got no source code.

May someone help me?

EDIT:
I´ve searched the regrestry because the moste solutions about this error are pointing to the regrestry but the key was not found and I dono what to do in this case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Msbind.dll is not registered on your machine. This dll is a part of VB6. You can install VB6 or find this dll, copy it on your machine and register manually (regsvr32 /i Msbind.dll).